# I need to remove the Horizontal Scrollbar on an overflown <DIV>

Tags: css

I have defined a  tag with a CSS attribute "overflow" set to "scroll". This is giving me both the vertical and the horizontal scroll bars. I only want the vertical scroll bar. What should i do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try using the

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

This will give you a vertical scroll-bar...

---

Using

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

will only show the scrollbar if it is necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Try using "`overflow-y: scroll;`" instead.  It's CSS3, but as far as I know, it's supported by every modern browser (IE6+, FF, Opera, Chrome/Safari/WebKit/etc.).

A quick explanation of the various `overflow`/`-x`/`-y` values, for those not familiar with them:

- `visible` – The default.  Content which does not fit "overflows" the box, usually appearing over or under adjacent content.
- `hidden` – Content which does not fit is "guillotined" — cut off at the edges of the box.
- `auto` – Content which does not fit causes a scroll bar to appear. Does not necessarily cause both scroll bars to appear at once; if content fits horizontally but not vertically, only a vertical scroll bar will appear.
- `scroll` – Similar to `auto`, but scroll bar(s) appear whether needed or not. AFAIK, mostly used to prevent centered content from "jumping" if a scroll bar needs to be added to dynamic (e.g. AJAX) content.

Comment: I have seen one browser that does not support overflow-x, overflow-y, but I can't remember which.  Probably an old version of firefox or Opera or something silly like that, so this solution is a good one as well.  Only thing is, with overflow-y:scroll, the vertical scroll bar will always be there even if it is not needed.

Comment: @Zoidberg — IIRC, both FF2 and Opera 9 support it, so an older browser would be my guess as well. And from the original question, I expect an "always-on" scroll bar is exactly what he wants. Of course, it works perfectly well with `auto`, `hidden`, or `visible`, too.

Comment: @Ben Blank Yeah, based on his question it sounds like that.  I guess my answer is partial to not showing the scroll bar if its not needed because I hate scroll bars.  My question is why didn't he accept your answer?

Comment: @Zoidberg — Perhaps trying to encourage another low-rep user? As long as he's helped, though, it's all good. :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
overflow:auto;
```

Comment: To the down voter... please provide a comment as to why you down voted.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a very old question but I stumbled across it today. If, like me, you only want the y-scrollbar and then only when it's needed, I found this works:

```
.myclass {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Cheers, Mark

Answer (score 1):

```
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:scroll;
```