# How to avoid horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css

Can anybody please look into my code

```
<html>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="txtFld">
            <input type="text"/>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
ul{margin:0;padding:0}
ul li{border-bottom:1px solid #f1f1f1;padding:5px}
.box{width:160px;overflow:auto;border:1px solid #ccc;height:150px}
.txtFld{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box}
.txtFld input{width:100%;}
```

Horizontal scrollbar is appearing in chrome and ie browsers. where did i make mistake ?

Comment: I am not getting horizontal scrollbars in Chrome, only vertical. And the vertical ones can be fixed by setting `height: auto` and removing `overflow: auto` in your `.box` style

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is old but the answer is :

You have to set the `box-sizing:border-box` property on the text input (and not on his parent div like you did).

It will work just fine, see it in the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rE6xW/2/

This is because the text input has padding(2px) and border(1px) by default and when you set it's width to 100%, it is `100%+2*[padding+border]` so you get an horizontal scroll bar because it is 6px wider than it's parent.
When you set the `box-sizing:border-box` property, then your `width:100%`property will be interpreted as :

> 100% = innerWidth + padding + border

I hope this will help someone.

.

Answer (score 0):

Its because

```
.txtFld input{width:100%;}
```

Change to

```
.txtFld input{width:50%;}
```

or whatever suits

Comment: the input should be full wide even do not have vertical scrollbar

Comment: so you just want to hide both scrollbars?

Comment: hiding scrollbar is not a problem. They should work naturally.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hide the scroll bar only, use

```
.box::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;                                                          
}
```

for Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't want a scroll bar on any element with a class of "box", you'll need to set **overflow** to **hidden**.

```
.box {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  height: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150px;
}
```

If you only want to disable the horizontal scroll bar, then set **overflow-x** to hidden.

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

If you don't want the entire page to have a horizontal scroll bar, then you'll want to set **overflow-x** on the **body** tag.

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your text box width being overridden somewhere else in the your project?

```
.txtFld input{
  width:100%;
}
```

When this is removed from your provided code it appears to have a horizontal bar only in IE and Chrome but works fine in Firefox. Maybe double check your CSS document and HTML.

Comment: Try this: `overflow-y: auto;` with the `overflow-x: hidden;` referenced here [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400992/i-need-to-remove-the-horizontal-scrollbar-on-an-overflown-div)

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the width of `.txtFld` to `auto`:

```
.txtFld input {
  width:auto;
}
```